# Search an ArrayList with multiple fields using only one field from a different ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

If there is an `ArrayList` for `moviesAvailable` and the list takes `title`, `year`, `genre`, `price`. How can I get a list of movies using an `ArrayList` of `genres`?

There is a toString method in the Movie class that prints out the movies. When I run the code everything past the if statement doesn't run because the condition is returned as false.

Comment: You can clearly see that you are calling the "equals" method of Genre, but you didn't override it, so you are using the default one, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `equals()` in your `Genre` class, so that you can compare instances of that class to each other.

Here's a quick implementation, which can easily be extended for additional functionality:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Genre)) {
        return false;
    }
    return ((Genre) o).name.equals(this.name);
}
```

Comment: Your method also is not null save. `new Genre(null).equals(new Genre(null))` throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp "Here's a **quick implementation**, which can **easily be extended for additional functionality**"

Comment: This method works, is this the only way to solve the problem or there there anything I can change in the code to make it work?

Comment: @TDizzle Overriding the `equals()` method is exactly what your code needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals method in Genre class to make if condition working, see below code

```
private String name;

Genre(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public boolean hasType(String genre) {

    return genre.equals(this.name);
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (!(o instanceof Genre)) {
      return false;
   }
   return this.name.equals(((Genre)o).name);
}
```

Comment: a better implementation would be:
`return (o instanceof Genre) ? ((Genre) o).name.equals(this.name) : false; `